# ubuntu 14.04 tty login problem

Tags: tty

I am facing a problem in my personal server vm where I cannot login to ubuntu using tty login. The username I type is not displayed, when I hit backspace, the cursor moves to the left on the prompt text and when I hit enter, the console login prompt appears again. What can I do to fix this problem.

Comment: Can you please provide more information. Any error are you getting?

Comment: none at all unfortunately.

Comment: I think that somehow the tty was given one or more `stty` commands; for example `stty -echo` to turn character echoing off, `stty erase ...` to change your backspace into another character. Its been a long time that I used there commands, so I am not sure how to remedy it. Another thought is that the keyboard layout has been redefined...